# Check if parent nodes are equal irrespective of children

Tags: javascript, html, element

I am looking for a quick way to check if 2 elements are equal to each other, irrespective of what children they have. isEqualNode doesn't work as it compares the children of the element also.

So, in this example, I want to make a function that if given the 2 `<div class="foo" style="background-color: green;">` elements as parameters, would return true, even though they have different children.

```
<div class="foo" style="background-color: green;">
  <h3>bar</h3>
  Hello
</div>

<div class="foo" style="background-color: green;">
  <div class="goat" />
</div>

<script>
  function checkIfParentNodesAreEqual(el1, el2) { /* magic */}

  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
  checkIfParentNodesAreEqual(els[0], els[1]) // I want this to return true
</script>
```

So I'm wondering, what would be the best way performance-wise to tell if these 2 elements are equal?

I know that we could do a shallow clone of both the nodes and compare the clones, or that we could remove all the children, compare the parents, and then re-attach the children, but I'm wondering if there is a faster way.

Comment: define **2 parents are equal**

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully its a little clearer

Comment: Would different inline styles make it not equal?

Comment: Yes @JohanP I am basically trying to find an isEqualNode function that doesnt compare children.

Comment: This is a much harder problem to solve then. Even `isEqualNode` will return `false` for these 2 nodes even if they have no children: `<div class="foo" style="background-color: green;color:red;">` and `<div class="foo" style="color:red;background-color: green;">`

Comment: @TysonHauke why don't you just compare the classes, you need to compare if they have the same style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gonna have to do a shallow copy of the nodes in order to compare them, as such:

```
function compareNodes (nodes, shallow) {
  if (shallow) nodes = nodes.map((node) => node.cloneNode(false))
  return nodes.every((node, index, nodes) => {
    let nextIndex = index + 1
    return nodes[nextIndex] ? node.isEqualNode(nodes[nextIndex]) : true
  })
}

compareNodes(Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('foo')), true)
```

But as you said, you're looking for an alternative that might be more efficient. I don't think the above implementation is wildly inefficient, but you have to test this yourself specifically for your application and see how it performs. An alternative that I can think of is using a Virtual DOM and utilizing its diffing algorithm, but they have their drawbacks as well - as outlined in [this blog post over at Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/face-off-virtual-dom-vs-incremental-dom-vs-glimmer/). You'll have to do some digging about that to find out which implementation you want to use. Although I believe you will get by with the above implementation just fine.

**Update:** I did some testing on the above implementation, comparing a total of 1,000 nodes, including doing a shallow copy of each of them, took on average 3ms on my system.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much for the link too, I've had a quick look and it looks like using a virtual DOM might be the way to go, but yeah as you said I need to do some more digging

Comment: Glad I could be of help! :) I did some testing of the performance of this implementation, and have added it to my answer as an update. Note however that mileage may vary depending on system and application.

Answer (score 2):

You can try cloning the nodes, remove their children and then compare.
You don't have to re-attach children as we are making a clone.

```
var eles = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
var parent1 = eles[0].cloneNode(true);
var parent2 = eles[1].cloneNode(true);

parent1.innerHTML = '';
parent2.innerHTML = '';

function checkIfParentNodesAreEqual(parent1, parent2) { /* magic */}
```

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

At some point the funtion *isSameNode()* was defined, but now it is preferred to use the `===` operator (triple `=`) instead, to validate if two elements are in deed the same element:

```
function checkIfParentNodesAreEqual(el1, el2) 
{ 
  /* magic */
  return( el1.parentElement === el2.parentElement );
}
```

Take a look at [HTML DOM parentElement Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp) in case you may prefer to use `parentNode` property, instead of `parentElement`.

Take a look at [HTML DOM isSameNode() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_issamenode.asp) for more details about the comparison.

Comment: With this approach, `<div class="foo" style="background-color: green;color:red">` will be true when other node is `< div class="foo" style="background-color: green;">` Not sure if that is considered `equal`.

Comment: @JohanP, maybe you are thinking of [isEqualNode()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_isequalnode.asp) which compares the characteristics (type, attributes, etc) of the nodes to determine if they are equal (no necesarily the same).